# Eliminate equally named paragraphs

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to eliminate equally named paragraphs (containing different strings of data, DNA in my case).

For example my file is:

```
>blue
1. agccttgatcgttac
2. tttactaaagatgat
3. agccttga
>orange
1. tttactaaagatg
2. agccttgatcgtt
3. tttacta
>blue
1. caatgcatgcaga 
2. agccttgatcgtt
3. tttactaaagatg
4. caatgca
```

I would like to remove all equally named paragraphs, leaving only one of them (in this case one of the ">"blue). Each paragraph starts with ">".  How could I do it?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate duplicate strings in the beginning of file, or strings, that are the same until space or comma or whatever punctuation you mean?

Comment: David, sorry, I want to eliminate (in this case) one header (-blue) and the associated strings (anothertextex) until the next symbol "-" of the next header. Strings are different from each other (all of them).

Comment: Let me put it this way: you want to eliminate  equally named paragraphs? This may involve some heavy `awk` usage. Edit your question and add: "Paragraph are delimited with ..." and state what character or string denotes end of paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^>/{seen=cnt[$0]++} !seen' file
>blue
1. agccttgatcgttac
2. tttactaaagatgat
3. agccttga
>orange
1. tttactaaagatg
2. agccttgatcgtt
3. tttacta
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, colleagues may offer more elegant way, but here is quick and dirty one:

```
cat in.txt |grep "^>"|sort|awk ' p == $0; { p = $0 }' >headers.txt
cp in.txt out.txt
while read in; do
    cat out.txt| sed "/^$in/,/^>/{//!d}"|sed "/^$in/d" >temp.txt
    mv temp.txt out.txt
done < headers.txt
```

Given `in.txt` as an input file, you get `out.txt` as output and list of deleted paragraph names in `headers.txt`.

Note, that I delete **ALL** occurrences of duplicate-named paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

using awk

```
awk -v RS="\">\"" '{c=0;name=name" "$1;split(name,arr);for(i in arr){if(arr[i]==$1){++c}};if(c==1){print RS $0;next}}' file > new_file
```

**example** if you have the data

```
">"orange
    tttactaaagatg
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttacta
">"blue
    caatgcatgcaga
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttactaaagatg
    caatgca
">"blue
    caatgcatgcaga
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttactaaagatg
    caatgca
">"orange

    tttactaaagatg
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttacta
">"green

    tttactaaagatg
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttacta
```

**results**

```
">"orange
    tttactaaagatg
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttacta

">"blue
    caatgcatgcaga
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttactaaagatg
    caatgca

">"green

    tttactaaagatg
    agccttgatcgtt
    tttacta
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple job for `awk`:

```
awk '/^>/ { print_it = 0; if (seen[$1]++ == 0) print_it = 1 }
          { if (print_it) print }'
```

This keeps the first paragraph with a given title.  If you need to keep the last such paragraph, you have to work a lot harder.